# Intel Intrinsic: Load interleaved float32

Tags: intel, sse, intrinsics

My RAM contains the following interleaved data:
float32 Real1, float32 Imag1, float32 Real2, float32 Imag2, ... , float32 Real4, float32 Imag4

I have to load into __m128: Real1, Real2, Real3, Real4
and into another __m128: Imag1, Imag2, Imag3, Imag4

Is it possible ?

Comment: Not very efficiently, e.g. you'd  have to use `shufps` (`_mm_shuffle_ps`) twice to get the output you want from two input vectors.  If possible, store your data deinterleaved, e.g. an  array of real parts and an array of imaginary parts, not one array of `complex double` elements.  See [Complex Mul and Div using sse Instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3211346) for an example of the shuffling required for complex-multiply of a single vector to get the output back into that inconvenient format.

Comment: Hi Peter. Thank you very much. In case I have to run FIR (for example) on float32 complex data, it will be more efficient to store the input in 2 different buffers: real, imaginary. Am I right ?

Comment: Yes, almost anything you want to do with a bunch of complex float data is more efficient with separate real[] and imag[] arrays, except maybe scattered access to only a small amount of your total data where you'd actually benefit from the spatial locality of keeping them together.  It's the same as with x[], y[], z[] geometry vectors instead of `struct{x,y,z}[]`, as discussed in https://deplinenoise.wordpress.com/2015/03/06/slides-simd-at-insomniac-games-gdc-2015/  In general, SoA (struct of arrays) instead of AoS (Array of Structs)

Comment: I just finished a signal processing project in ARM (cortex A53). This architecture has up to 128bit intrinsic operations but also for interleaved data.  I wonder why Intel has no such mnemonics.

Comment: I've read that ARM `ld2` loads for interleaved data aren't as efficient, at least on some cores.  But also, one uop on Intel microarchitectures can only ever write a single register, vs. ARM having multiple instructions that write 2 registers (like some shuffles, load-pair, and ld2).  Since Intel designed their vector instruction sets after the P6 microarchitecture (which their current CPUs still are still somewhat based on), it makes sense they'd mostly introduce instructions that can run as a single uop, thus no two-register loads.

Comment: Just wanted to note that for questions like this, I think the best option is usually to just look at what clang does with `__builtin_shufflevector`.  For example: https://godbolt.org/z/cG6o9z67x. You can see that the compiler generates shufps instructions (and the values it uses), then if you need to you can head over to the [Intel Intrinsics Guide](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html) and search for the instruction to figure out the intrinsic name.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you store your data in an array

```cpp
struct complex_t {
   float32_t re;
   float32_t im;
};

complex_t complex_array[N];
```

To vectorize it, you will need to perform two loads:

```cpp
__m128 complex0 = _mm_loadu_ps(complex_array + i);
__m128 complex1 = _mm_loadu_ps(complex_array + i + 2);
```

Each vector register contains two complex numbers [ x0, y0, x1, y1 ].

To deinterlave them, use `_mm_shuffle_ps`.

```cpp
__m128 re = _mm_shuffle_ps(complex0, complex1, _MM_SHUFFLE(0, 2, 0, 2));
__m128 im = _mm_shuffle_ps(complex0, complex1, _MM_SHUFFLE(1, 3, 1, 3));
```

Bear in mind, that, depending on your use case, you don't need to deinterleave data in vector register. For example, complex addition doesn't require deinterleaving. Complex multiplication can be implemented using `_mm_addsub_ps` intrinsic.

Comment: Or much better, arrange your data in memory so it's not interleaved in the first place.  Like separate arrays of real and imaginary parts, or in `struct chunk { float real[8], imag[8]; }` (or `[16]` if you want to use 512-bit vectors).

Comment: Not always possible.

Comment: I know, that's why I upvoted this answer.  But any time performance and complex numbers get mentioned, it's important to point out that storing them interleaved like `std::complex` sucks for SIMD. Often better if you can design all your code to work with a different format so you don't have to deal with it in the vectorized parts.